# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index

Tags: java, android, arraylist, listadapter

I have an arraylist and am using an ImageButton to delete items from the list. If I delete 3 items from the same position the app crashes with an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I can't figure how to change the array position of an item after deleting the items that come before it.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ExRow expense = expenseList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(expense.getTitle());
    holder.amount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the item on remove/button click
            expenseList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, expenseList.size());

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling both `notifyItemRemoved()` and `notifyItemRangeChanged()` ? only one should be enough

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of your exception and make your code example more complete? It's for example completely unclear what an object `expenseList` is.

Comment: try to replace `ExRow expense = expenseList.get(position);` with `ExRow expense = expenseList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible solutions for this.

This one is ideal according to me

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExRow expense = expenseList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    holder.title.setText(expense.getTitle());
    holder.amount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the item on remove/button click
            int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            expenseList.remove(adapterPosition);
            notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
            notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! Could you explain this so I can make sure I understand?

Comment: In this part of my blog http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#common_mistakes i have mentioned the difference between LayoutPosition and AdapterPosition. Once you the difference, you can understand that the LayoutPosition which you were using as final variable remains same even after deleting n items from list. But using holder's adapterPosition will always give you the current position of holder in the list.

Comment: Thank you. this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In an `ArrayList`, when you remove an element from an index, the index of the elements after that are shifted to the left. An example:

```
Index | Value
0       A
1       B
2       C
3       D
```

When you delete index 2 from the array, here's the result:

```
Index | Value
0       A
1       B
2       D
```

So my guess is: You are removing the index `position` from your list and at some point, `position` is simply higher than the amount of elements in your list.

*Update*:
Some inspiration for a solution below. It's hard to find a good solution without understanding the use case, really.

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Remove the item on remove/button click
        if(position >= expenseList.size()) return;
        expenseList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, expenseList.size());
    }
```

Or:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Remove the item on remove/button click
        if(expenseList.size() == 0) return;
        if(position >= expenseList.size()) {
            position = expenseList.size() -1;
        }
        expenseList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, expenseList.size());
    }
```

And so on.

Comment: You could check whether the ArrayList's length is greater than position. Or you use an iterator to remove items from the list. Or you compute the position properly.

Comment: Not sure if this works but arraylist has a indexOf method which can be used to get position of the object. Try combining that with remove. ie mylist.remove(mylist.indexOf(myObject));

Comment: Thank you. This answer did come close to fixing it. The app no longer crashed but when 1 item was left it was not able to be deleted. I used the 1st recommendation. For the 2nd, if(position >= expenseList.size()) {
            position = expenseList.size() -1;
        } if the result of the condition was correct, "position = expenseList.size() -1;" position could not be recognized

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, expenseList.size());

notifyItemRemoved(position); this is to enough for removing an item from list.

Comment: No its not enough. If you read the docs, notifyItemRemoved will not update the resources. You have to handle it manually.

Comment: Can put Exception Log?

Answer (score 0):

Make your model final and use it to determine position.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ExRow expense = expenseList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(expense.getTitle());
    holder.amount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the item on remove/button click
            int pos = expenseList.indexOf(expense);

            if (pos == -1)
                return;

            expenseList.remove(pos);
            notifyItemRemoved(pos);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, expenseList.size());

        }
    });
}
```